# Question regarding publishing to a user's facebook feed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently I am building a small application that allows a user to sign in to their Facebook account and update their status from within the application.

However, the Facebook API does not seem well documented and I am having trouble locating sources of information that are relevant to the specific project that I am building.

Does anyone know of any articles that might be of use to me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is there, scattered around and difficult to find, but there. These two links may help if you are looking to post to someone's wall. FB.ui is sort of a multi-purpose call that will present different dialogs, prompting the user for action. It's far easier to implement than it is find.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.ui/